# forming histogram plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-analysis

suppose I want to plot 2 histogram subplots on the same window in python, one below the next.  The data from these histograms will be read from a file containing a table with attributes A and B.

In the same window, I need a plot of A vs the number of each A and a plot of B vs the number of each B - directly below the plot of A.  so suppose the attributes were height and weight, then we'd have a graph of height and number of people with said height and below it a separate graph of weight and number of people with said weight.

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
frame = pd.read_csv('data.data', header=None)
subplot.hist(frame['A'], frame['A.count()'])
subplot.hist(frame['B'], frame['B.count()'])
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#df = pd.read_csv('data.data', header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': numpy.random.random_integers(0,10,30),
                   'B': numpy.random.random_integers(0,10,30)})
print df['A']

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1.set_title('A')
ax1.set_ylabel('number of people')
ax1.set_xlabel('height')

ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
ax2.set_title('B')
ax2.set_ylabel('number of people')
ax2.set_xlabel('weight')

ax1.hist(df['A'])
ax2.hist(df['B'])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: double histogram]

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas you can make [histograms](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) like this:

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frame = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
frame.hist(layout = (2,1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm confused by the second part of the question. Do you want four separate subplots?